# How to get id from inside div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the id from the inside div. I have many div with class control but I want to get parent div id. How to get?

http://jsfiddle.net/cngt2ef6/7/

```js
$(".getid").click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest('div').hasClass("control).attr("id"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control" id="spa">
  Content
</div>
<div class="control" id="test">
  <div class="method">
    <a href="#" class="getid">Getid</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control" id="awesome">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: Change `.closest('div').hasClass("control)` to `.closest('div.control')`

Comment: You can use .parents() method of jQuery.
$(this).parents(".control").attr("id");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from :

1. The `closest` selector that will return the first parent `div` (what is not what we need here).
2. The **[`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** since it will return a boolean if the element has the given class or not. (in your case the first parent doesn't have the given class `control`)

Instead of using `hasClass()` you need to use the `class` selector directely in the `closest()` method like:

```
$(this).closest('div.control').attr("id");
```

```js
$(".getid").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('div.control').attr("id"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control" id="spa">
  Content
</div>
<div class="control" id="test">
  <div class="method">
    <a href="#" class="getid">Getid</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control" id="awesome">
  Content
</div>
Js:
```

Comment: @ Zakaria:Can you answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424524/how-to-call-a-function-inside-same-function-and-outside-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Besides `closest()` - which return the first single node parent - already mentioned you can use `parents()` , but in this case  will return multiple nodes with the element/class/id targeted.

It is just an alternative to `closest()` in this case scenario

```js
$(".getid").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parents('.control').attr("id"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control" id="spa">
  Content
</div>
<div class="control" id="test">
  <div class="method">
    <a href="#" class="getid">Getid</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control" id="awesome">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: You can, but it's irrelevant here - and you should indicate that `.closest()` finds the single parent that is closest while `.parents()` could return multiple nodes.

Comment: In this case there is no multiple nodes therefore no need to mention that I think :)

Comment: `closest()` is preferred when searching for a single ancestor, as it stops after the first match.

Comment: Future question: I got this answer from ^^here^^ and it states I can use .parents() as an exact replacement for .closest() - why am I getting multiple results?   Just be complete.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my friend I'm fully aware of that, I'm just giving another option

Comment: Nice alternative solution :)