# How to call a function inside same function and outside in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function inside that same function and outside also. How does it in javascript?

**Js:**

```
someFunction(function repeat(result) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + result.winner;
    if (result.winner) {
        someFunction(repeat);
    }
});
someFunction.repeat();
```

Comment: why would you want to do this. .... this creates an endless loop ....

Comment: I have more if condition..So I will call only with some condition

Comment: Declare both functions before using them. Either as a variable ( expression ) or as a declaration.

Comment: Can you edit mycode?

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/bederuyizo See the Console, try something like this

Comment: I tried but that condition  I am not using..i want to call same function inside that same function

Comment: can you give me a link to what you are trying?

Comment: I need like this:  function One(){
      console.log("One");
      if(somecodion){One();}
    }
 
    One();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var someFunction = function( callback ) {
  // Do some things that belong to someFunction, like creating the result object.
  var result = {
    winner: true
  };
  // Call the repeat function, using the result as the parameter.
  callback( result );
};
var endless_loop_protection = 0;
var repeat = function( result ) {
  // Write the result somewhere
  console.log( result.winner + ': ' + endless_loop_protection );
  // faking the if clauses that prevent the endless loop.
  endless_loop_protection += 1;
  if ( result.winner && endless_loop_protection < 10 ) {
    // Do everything again if there's still a winner in the result.
    someFunction( repeat );
  }
};
someFunction( repeat );
```

---

Depending on what exactly else is inside the someFunction function and the repeat function, a structure like this could work better:

```js
var get_result = function() {
  // Create a random result.
  return {
    winner: Math.random() < 0.5
  };
};
// This will keep looping until get_result returns a result with winner = true.
// So the amount of times this will log is random each time you call it.
var handle_results_until_winner = function( get_result ) {
  var result = get_result();
  console.log( result.winner );
  if ( !result.winner ) handle_results_until_winner( get_result );
};
handle_results_until_winner( get_result );
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to implement it using recursion, this might help you.Change you condition and output in code as you expect.

```js
function someFunction(result) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + result;
     result--;
   
    if (result===0) {
       return;
     }
     
     return someFunction(result);
}
 someFunction(5);
```